# How do you make a site check which browser its using then select the right style sheet?

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I'm working with Joomla 1.5 and I need to use a separate style sheet for ie7 as it doesn't display correctly.  I'm unsure of the php code to use to make the site check which browser it is using and then which style sheet to read when it does.  Please help, I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 4):

You should use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) in your `<head>` HTML to load a stylsheet if IE7 is detected. You *could* do it with PHP, but using conditional comments is *far* easier and is a much better way to do this.

Put all your hacks/changes in a separate CSS file and load it with

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Make sure you put this *after* your normal stylesheet so that, in the event of IE7 being used, the hacks/other styles overwrite the ones in your main CSS file.

Comment: @donutdan4114 I think you'll find that I have already linked to that page, but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: LOL, great minds think alike... That's funny, can't really see the link color on my monitor, its just the __slightest__ shade of blue.

Comment: It could be made a little more obvious I suppose. _My_ monitor makes seeing the light grey background behind inline code barely visible!

Comment: Thanks for that, that seems to have done the trick!  Only thing is, some things it is still reading off the other style sheet I think, I'm getting an orange box that I shouldn't be and when I take out the piece of CSS in the style sheet it would be reading for this, it still stays.  I did put the code after the original style sheet.

Comment: I can't really help much here. Make sure the IE7 CSS file is actually being loaded (Firebug or View Source -> open CSS link, etc) and that you have the correct CSS selectors.

Comment: Yep, definitely loading, I'm using the developer tools in IE and it's showing up.  Thanks for all your help, I'll try a joomla developers forum :)